# Run a python HttpServer before run a iOS project in Xcode

Tags: python, ios, xcode, simplehttpserver, run-script

I’m trying to run a http server before run an iOS project. I've added a script  `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 9527` in `Run Script`.
[image]
It's OK when I run it in Terminal,
 But when I clicked the `Run` button in Xcode, it stoped like

[image]

When I stoped the project，Xcode showed some error log:

*Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 9527 ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "**main**", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SimpleHTTPServer.py", line 235, in 
    test()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SimpleHTTPServer.py", line 231, in test
    BaseHTTPServer.test(HandlerClass, ServerClass)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 599, in test
    httpd.serve_forever()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 236, in serve_forever
    poll_interval)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 155, in _eintr_retry
    return func(*args)
KeyboardInterrupt*

Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your build is remaining within this phase because the command you are executing will not terminate until you request it to. Most likely, the web server is running correctly, however Xcode is waiting for it to terminate, which it won't do until you click the 'stop' button.

The stack trace which you see is normal when you stop the inbuilt web server within Python. You'll see a similar message if you use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to exit it when using Terminal.

Generally, the 'execute shell' phases of your build should run commands which perform a task and then exit by themselves, however if you're trying to make the web server run for the duration of the build, you'd need to employ two phases. One phase at the beginning of the build to start the web server and fork it and another phase at the end of the build to terminate it. Whilst variables don't persist between built phases from my experience, you could write the PID to a file and then read it within the later stage.

Aside from this solution, I'd suggest rethinking if you need to run a server as part of your build. If you start to use some from of Continuous Integration in the future, or just want to run multiple builds at the same time, additional complexities of allocating port numbers will introduce a challenge.